# Can you check the date from a Microsoft server, and set a variable for a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that I only want to run once a day, here is the code:

```
set ACTUALDATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
set /p BEFOREDATE=<date.txt
if %ACTUALDATE% == %BEFOREDATE% GOTO L
echo %ACTUALDATE%>date.txt
start Minecraft/Launcher/Minecraft.exe

C:/Python24/python.exe timer.py

start "" cmd /c "echo Time is almost up!&echo(&pause"


tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe*32" 2>NUL 

:L
C:/Python24/python.exe timer2.py

taskkill /f /im javaw.exe
```

This works fine, it runs and then terminates Minecraft after the time, which is judged based on the python files. This isn't the problem, the problem is that the user is not super happy about this program, and I am trying to work around the fact he can just change the date on his computer and rerun the program.

Is there a way to set "ACTUALDATE" from a server or some sort so that he cannot change the date. If there is any way around this work around it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `net time \\servername` (/set if you want to change the local time)

Comment: accurate answer to the question +1. But, there is a second question latent in the post, how to prevent a user to change the system date.

Comment: just put net time on top of the script so you check the server time, not the local one. BTW I would not use a batch if i dont want users to view / edit the script...

Comment: I know, I was going to change it to exe when I was finished, but the user wouldn't even know how to edit any way. Thank I will try that.

Comment: All right so I tried this: `net time /rtsdomain:time.nist.gov /set` and I get the message: `Could not locate time-server.` I have tried this with all the servers Microsoft shows in the internet menu of the time date settings. Is there another way I could get this to work?

Comment: Do you mean with another computer on the network? I tried that to and the message `The service has not been started.` occurs.

Comment: Maybe y ou can find help here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2009/08/07/net-time-and-w32time.aspx

Comment: I looked at it and it and it doesn't seem to help to much. I talked to a buddy of mine and he said open port 123 in my router, so I am going to play around with that.